# D3 color selector using directive scope returns always first color

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569205/d3-scale-category20b-always-returning-first-color) but the answer doesn't answer anything.

I'm using D3 inside an AngularJs directive. This directive (called pattern) is created with a scope property patternIndex, which is bound with '='. If I create 3 patterns they have indices 0,1,2. Inside this directive I'm drawing circles. I want the circles of each pattern instance to have a different color.

At the top of my directive link() function I create the color scale.

`var color = d3.scale.category10();`

Then in de d3 svg code I draw the circles based on a data structure called nodes.

```
var spots = g.selectAll('circle');
spots = spots.data(nodes);
spots.enter().append('circle')
  .style('fill', 'white')
  .attr({
     r: 10,
     cx: function(d) { return d.x; },
     cy: function(d) { return d.y; }
   })
   .attr('stroke', function(d, i) {
     var x = scope.patternIndex;
     console.log('pattern', x, 'color', color(x));
     console.log('circle', i, 'color', color(i));
     return color(i);
   });
```

The thing is this doesn't work. `color(x)` always returns the first color. But if I instead use the circle index to get the color `color(i)` than it works fine! So to be sure the patternIndex is actually correct i printed the values and here's the output for 3 patterns with each 4 circles:

```
pattern 0 color #1f77b4 
circle 0 color #1f77b4
pattern 0 color #1f77b4
circle 1 color #ff7f0e
pattern 0 color #1f77b4
circle 2 color #2ca02c
pattern 0 color #1f77b4
circle 3 color #d62728 
pattern 1 color #1f77b4 
circle 0 color #ff7f0e 
pattern 1 color #1f77b4
circle 1 color #1f77b4 
pattern 1 color #1f77b4 
circle 2 color #2ca02c
pattern 1 color #1f77b4 
circle 3 color #d62728 
pattern 2 color #1f77b4
circle 0 color #ff7f0e
pattern 2 color #1f77b4 
circle 1 color #2ca02c 
pattern 2 color #1f77b4
circle 2 color #1f77b4 
pattern 2 color #1f77b4 
circle 3 color #d62728
```

Eh? As you can see, the pattern index based color is always #1f77b4.

Another thing I don't get is that the first "circle 0" is different from the second and third "circle 0", but the colors on the screen appear the same for each of the 3 directive instances.

I'm really confused.

Comment: What is the type of `patternIndex` are you sure it is **not** a string ? Try to do `var x = parseInt(scope.patternIndex);`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's a number. I've used typeof to confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with my understanding of D3s ordinal scales. I found the answer here:

[JavaScript/D3: The “same” function call yields different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872201/javascript-d3-the-same-function-call-yields-different-result?rq=1)

So the reason this is happening is that the ordinal scales, without giving explicit input domain mapping, start to map based on the number you pass in on the first call.

```
var color = d3.scale.category10()
```

This creates a new orginal scale. It will return the first color wether you call color(0) or color(4). It returns the next color on the second call *if* the argument is different.

In my case the calls with the pattern index all returned the same color even though they were color(0), color(1) and color(2), because they were the first calls made on a new scale instance.

Then the circles where drawn and they all started with a different color offset, because the instances each received a different argument on the first call, resulting in a different input domain mapping for each of them.

So to get what I want I have to declare color like this:

```
 var color = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(0,10));
```

I think the docs should probably warn about this! I'm glad I now know how it works but it can be extremely confusing.